# On Ubuntu does Shoes require Ruby1.8 or Ruby1.9?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have only installed Ruby1.9 on my machine. Have some kind of problems with the programs I am trying to write using Shoes. Am wondering if this is a version issue.

I am trying to do some stuff over ssl.

Comment: You are trying some stuff over ssl?

Comment: Yes I was. I asked that in another question. Turned out Shoes doesn't support ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoes comes with its own Ruby version embedded in the script you download. It is completely self-contained as far as I can tell.

Comment: How or where did you get that information. This could be very useful for me to debug ?

Comment: I think it was mentioned on the mailing list. Also, if you do a ./shoes2.run --help it will give you instructions on how to extract the whole directory, then you can look at the embedded files more closely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know what is "Shoes" but i found this:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shoes

according to that "shoes (0.r396-5)" Depend on "rubygems1.8"

Comment: Also that shoes is a bit old, am using the one downloaded from shoes website