# How do I use Ruby1.9 with Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes, fiber

Shoes wraps it's own Ruby install, right?

I can't use Fiber which is a Ruby1.9 feature. And, I want to use a Fiber for creating a generator.

Here's my code (so you can make sure the problem isn't with my code):

```
class BrownianGenerator
  def initialize
    @x = 0
    @fiber = Fiber.new do
      loop do 
        @x = @x+rand; 
        Fiber.yield @x
      end
    end
  end
  def next; @fiber.resume end
  def rewind; @x=0 end
end
```

and if I made a shoes app like this:

```
Shoes.app do
  @b = BrownianGenerator.new
end
```

if I pull up the shoes console, I see the error:

```
uninitialized constant #<class:0xblah>::BrownianGenerator::Fiber
```

Since, it's saying Fiber is an uninitialized constant, either something is wrong with my code or this Ruby version doesn't know about the Fiber class - the latter should be the case.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402905/on-ubuntu-does-shoes-require-ruby1-8-or-ruby1-9) question on determining the version of Ruby (which is 1.8 for my mac install), but I don't know how I would change the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could use aman gupta's "poor man's fibers" or try doing ::Fiber
or what not.
GL!
-r

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Green Shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes).

It's functionality is based off of _why's original implementation, but it's packaged as a Gem and built specifically for 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

So I jumped into freenode #shoes and found out that the nightly build of shoes is using Ruby1.9. I haven't had time to try building it yet, but that should solve my problem.